# getting connection names from excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to select pivot names under each worksheet.  I'd like to find out how to get the data connection name for each pivot tables.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim pvf As PivotField
Dim pvi As PivotItem
Dim x As String
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("Log").Activate
Columns("H:L").Select
i = 1
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws.PivotTables.Count > 0 Then
    For Each pvt In ws.PivotTables
      ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = ws.Name
      ActiveCell.Offset(i, 1) = pvt.Name
      'ActiveCell.Offset(i, 2) = conn.Name
      i = i + 1
    Next pvt
  End If
Next ws
```

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "data connection name" and can you paste the first few rows of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data connection name of the current pivot table, use this:

```
pvt.PivotCache.WorkbookConnection
```

Note that it will throw an error if the pivot table is not using a workbook connection so you should check first:

```
If pvt.PivotCache.SourceType = xlExternal Then
   ActiveCell.Offset(i, 2) = pvt.PivotCache.WorkbookConnection
End If
```

Comment: If this works, please select the arrow on the left to accept the answer (noticed you are new so just in case you didn't know). :)